# What is the "+" closure in this array extension doing?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

How is the function of "+" returning an array that looks like its adding all the preceding numbers of each index? I get the 0 + 1 = 1, 1 + 2 = 3, 1+2+3+4 = 10 but I'm having trouble making the connection of how the combine function does this with just a "+"

```
extension Array {
func accumulate<U>(initial: U, combine: (U, Element) -> U) -> [U] {
    var running = initial
    return self.map { next in
        running = combine(running, next)
        return running
        }
    }
}

let test = [1,2,3,4]
test.accumulate(0, combine: +)
// returns [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: This is just a demonstration of how the built-in `reduce` works. Explained in this section of my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_array_enumeration_and_transformation

Comment: Have a look at the "Operator Functions" section in the Swift reference.

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks, this is the missing piece i needed to connect the dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combine` is a function. Saying `combine(running, next)` *calls* that function, which takes two parameters. In Swift, `+` (like every other operator) *is* a function. Thus, when `combine` is `+`, calling `combine` adds `running` to `next` and returns the result.